# ask about canvas in html5

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have 1 canvas with width=300px, height=600px. I want to drawImage 1 image with original size (60px ,90px) with below code but the result shows image size width= 60x and height= 360px. please fix it for me. Thanks!

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = './img/t2.png';
    img.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 60, 90)
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, canvas has 2 different sizes (dimensions), style size and internal size. The style size is used to display on page and internal is for calculating the drawing elements coordinates.
I don't see you set any sizes, which I assume, you only set style size in CSS. This mean, that internal size is default 300x150

Here is a little demonstration when 300x600 set via CSS only:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9pPCK70Rw0k3wethMHb1qMaIB0VjeWLy57vYgSzKbF7oJuvO2nA0Nakk-95cvibWUDcEhYkfCKvdPKT03tXZd4M5jdhIEibLO9qw-XE=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj';
    img.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 60, 90)
    };
```

```css
canvas
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

And same thing with proper internal sizes:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    c.width = 300;
    c.height = 600;
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9pPCK70Rw0k3wethMHb1qMaIB0VjeWLy57vYgSzKbF7oJuvO2nA0Nakk-95cvibWUDcEhYkfCKvdPKT03tXZd4M5jdhIEibLO9qw-XE=w1024-h683-n-l50-sg-rj';
    img.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 60, 90)
    };
```

```css
canvas
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I understood where I was lacking. Your explanation is very detailed and easy to understand. Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me. Thank you very much!